# Unable to load precompiled lua bytecode with loadfile or load

Tags: lua, bytecode

I've compiled my lua code using luac53 and have the bytecode file. The problem is loadfile doesn't seem to want to load it and returns nil.

```
local func = loadfile("file.txt")//Returns nil
```

Load also returns nil after the following:

```
local file = io.open("file.txt", "rb")
local str = file:read("*a")
file:close()
local func = load(str, "bt")//Returns nil
```

The file is being loaded as a string here, but neither load or loadfile are doing anything. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: This isn't your problem, but generally speaking, a `.txt` file should be a text file of some sort. Sticking compiled Lua bytecode into a "text file" is bad form.

Comment: I've also tried loading the bytecode from a standard .lua file to no avail either. This is really confusing to me.

Comment: Like I said, that's not your problem. Your real problem probably has to do with the current directory when executing the script (that is, the file isn't in the directory that is presently "current") or some other pathing issue. But there's no way to know without being on your actual computer.

Comment: When using the load method, str loaded from the file just file. Lua is deciding to be difficult to me today I guess :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Lua practice for functions that issue errors is to return `nil` followed by an error message. The Lua file you provide is probably generating an error at load time, so it is returning that. But you never look for a second return value.

`assert` can be useful here, since it takes a value to test and a string to print if there is an error. So if you did `assert(loadstring(...))`, it would print the error that `loadstring` returned, if it errored out. As a bonus, `assert` will return the first parameter it is given, so if `loadstring` succeeded, `assert(loadstring(...))` will return the loaded chunk.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm getting the message "size_t size mismatch in precompiled chunk.". I don't really know why though because the lua file has no errors for sure and was compiled with the Lua compiler. Any ideas about why this is happening?

Comment: @Varscott11: That is a different question, one that can only be answered by providing the actual script. As well as what generated it (ie: the precompiler).

Comment: Well thanks for your help. At least I'm closer to finding the problem. Cheers!

Comment: @Varscott11, "size mismatch" means that the script was precompiled in a different platform than the one you're trying to load it in.